# How to Move Customized Action/Button place in existing screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

We have a requirement to add a new “Back Button” to the existing screen i.e. Preowned Vehicles Returns. I have added the "Back Button" button but it is coming at last, we would like to move this button before the Save action.

Could you please provide your thoughts here?

[image]

Comment: Could you simply override a currently existing button instead?

Comment: The order of the buttons on the graph is based on the order of the PXAction in your graph: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48672995/2056380   also you can do as the answer provided in a graph extension if your graph is an extension. Is this a custom graph (not a graph extension) and if so how are you declaring your buttons/pxactions?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use a graph extension to move the button? You can override *Initialize()* in your graph extension and use *Actions.Move()* to move an action button after another action button. I'm not sure if there's a method that places a button *before* another but you can move them twice. For example: If you want to move 3 before 1 in [1, 2, 3], you can place 3 immediately after 1, then place 1 immediately after 3.

```
public class GraphExtension : PXGraphExtension<BaseGraph>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        Base.Actions.Move(nameof(Base.Save), nameof(Base.BackButton), true);
        Base.Actions.Move(nameof(Base.BackButton), nameof(Base.Save), true);
    }
}
```

[image: Before swapping buttons]

becomes

[image: After swapping buttons]